# PageTable memory leak Windows 8.1

Tags: memory-leaks

I have noticed in resource monitor that usually my RAM usage hovers around 80% which is weird when I only have a webbrowser and skype running since I have 8gb RAM.

I tried to find the memory leak myself and finally found this:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDSUf.png

I have a few more applications running on the screenshot, but even if I kill every application the RAM usage will still be 60%+

I can't make any sense out of that.

Comment: When was the last time you did a real reboot?

Comment: Some days ago, but reboots doesn't help. The RAM usage ramps up to 60%+ quickly after a reboot.

Comment: I'm having this same issue; found this question while searching for an answer myself. Any progress?